# Numeric value which is entered in a text filed with WebDriver using Java is deleted automatically

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver with java. I want to input some numeric value in a text field by using Java. I am using the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("igtxtctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_WTxtZip")).sendKeys("25025");
```

But after entering the value completely, the entered value is erased automatically. 
After the value is stored, I have to click on tab (using script), so that the City field is populated automatically after running the back end process.

I have achieved the same thing using Selenium RC by using below code:

```
selenium.typeKeys("igtxtctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_WTxtZip", "25025");
Thread.sleep(x);
selenium.keyPress("igtxtctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_WTxtZip", "9");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "erased automatically"? Do you see the new value in the text box, and then you see it deleted? When you work manually on that page, do you have any problem typing values to that field?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The entered value is deleted, no value is displayed in the field. when I work manually on that page, all the field values are entered properly and Account is created successfully.

Comment: Is this problem specific to one single field? Do you have any events (keyup,keydown for ex.) or validations associated with that element? If you do, try again without the events.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is with all the text fields where i have to enter the numeric value. I don't have any events or validations on these fields except ZIP code field, here on valid zip code, City will be displayed.

Comment: Can you send a URL to that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try some thing like this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("igtxtctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_WTxtZip")).sendKeys("25025");
```

after typing zip code just try to click some where else in the page

```
driver.findElement(By.id("igtxtctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_WTxtZip")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

OR

Try with [Actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class.

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id("igtxtctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_WTxtZip")), "").perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved my problem by using the Action class. This issue can be closed now.

Answer (score 1):

From inspecting your code, I see that there is client-side logic based on that zip element. There is a post-back to the server to determine the city. The trigger to the post-back is the tab key.

This means that if you want to effectively test your page, you must send the tab key.

Comment: How do i send the tab key using webdriver.

Comment: Assaf, Thanks for your answer. The above answer has worked for me. Thanks again.